# Editing a Django model after saving it

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

models.py

```
class TelefoneIP(models.Model):
        mac = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="Este campo deve ter 12 digitos")
        modelo = models.ForeignKey(ModeloTelefoneIP)
        cliente_atual = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
        fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(Fornecedor)
        datacompra = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de compra", null=True, blank=True)
        nfcompra = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nota fiscal de compra")

class MovimetoTelefoneIP(models.Model):
        equipamento = models.ForeignKey(TelefoneIP)
        cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
        nfvenda = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nota fiscal de saída", null=True, blank=True)
        datavenda = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de saída", null=True, blank=True)
```

admin.py:

```
class TelefoneIPInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = MovimetoTelefoneIP
        extra = 1
        list_filter = ['nome']

class TelefoneIPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('mac', 'modelo', 'fornecedor', )
        list_filter = ['cliente_atual__nome']
        search_fields = ['mac']
        inlines = [TelefoneIPInline]
```

The question is, when I edit an Inline, can I set the value of cliente_atual (on TelefoneIP) as cliente (on MovimentoTelefoneIP) when I save it?

Thanks.

PS: I typed this code inside MovimentoTelefoneIP but didn't work too..
The field cliente_atual updated but the inline data was not saved.
I also tried Hassek's code and nothing..

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            MovimetoTelefoneIP.save()
            equipamento = self.equipamento
            equipamento.cliente_atual = self.cliente
            equipamento.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you have to override the save from the form and add that form to the admin:

```
class TelefoneIpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TelefoneIp

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(TelefoneIpForm, self).save(commit=commit)         

        equipamento = instance.equipamento
        equipamento.cliente = instance.cliente_atual
        equipamento.save()

class TelefoneIPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('mac', 'modelo', 'fornecedor', )
    list_filter = ['cliente_atual__nome']
    search_fields = ['mac']
    inlines = [TelefoneIPInline]
    form = TelefoneIpForm
```

I haven't test the code so if the info can't be accessed like showed in the code just inspect the object debugging it with **pdb**

Comment: did you try to debug it? what exception it throws?

Comment: unbound method save() must be called with MovimetoTelefoneIP instance as first argument (got nothing instead).
I also posted a code above that worked 50%.

Comment: This debug was made with the code I've posted. Yours didn't return eny error. But didn't change any field.

Comment: just edited, you have to change the form and add that one to the admin view, my bad for skipping that important info heh

Comment: When I tried to save again I got: TelefoneIPAdmin.form does not inherit from BaseModelForm.

Comment: just edited, the form must inherit from ModelForm, that should do.

Comment: Now I got this: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type.

Comment: damn I have to stop editing while I am sleepy, that's because the super should be calling the right class, just edited.

Comment: It tried to aceess TelefoneIP: 'TelefoneIP' object has no attribute 'equipamento'

Answer (score 0):

I've found another logic way to solve my problem. But I'm still in doubt: [Access data from a related class in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693635/access-data-from-a-related-class-in-django/)