# Access data from a related class in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
class TelefoneIPInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = MovimentoTelefoneIP
        extra = 1
        list_filter = ['nome']

class TelefoneIPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('mac', 'modelo', 'fornecedor', )
        list_filter = ['cliente__nome']
        search_fields = ['mac']
        inlines = [TelefoneIPInline]
        actions = [export_as_csv_action("Exportar para Excel", fields=['mac','modelo','cliente'])]
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to use a field from MovimentoTelefoneIP that is a related class of TelefoneIP as a parameter in list_display, list_display or and in "fields" in actions.

Here's my models:

```
class TelefoneIP(models.Model):
        mac = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="Este campo deve ter 12 digitos")
        modelo = models.ForeignKey(ModeloTelefoneIP)
        cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name="Cliente Atual")
        fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(Fornecedor)
        datacompra = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de compra", null=True, blank=True)
        nfcompra = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nota fiscal de compra", blank=True, null=True)
        obs = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

class MovimentoTelefoneIP(models.Model):
        equipamento = models.ForeignKey(TelefoneIP)
        cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
        nfvenda = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Nota fiscal de saída", null=True, blank=True)
        datavenda = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de saída", null=True, blank=True)
```

Thanks.

Tried with Chris's answer:

```
class TelefoneIPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        cliente = MovimentoTelefoneIP.objects.all()
        list_display = ('mac', 'modelo','get_clientes')
        search_fields = ['mac']
        list_filter = ['get_clientes']
        def get_clientes(self, obj):
                clientes = [m.cliente for m in obj.MovimentoTelefoneIP_set.all()]
                return u', '.join(clientes)
        get_clientes.short_description = 'Clientes'
        inlines = [TelefoneIPInline]
        actions = [export_as_csv_action("Exportar para Excel", fields=['mac','modelo','fornecedor'])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a method on your `ModelAdmin` that returns its value:

```
list_display('get_related_field')
...
def get_related_field(self, obj):
    return obj.related_object.some_field
get_related_field.short_description = 'Some Field' # Column header
get_related_field.admin_order_field = 'related_object__some_field'
```

You should probably add:

```
list_select_related = True
```

as well, so that it doesn't generate a query each time.

**UPDATE**

No, that's not correct. You want something like this:

```
 def get_clientes(self, obj):
    clientes = [m.cliente for m in obj.movimentotelefoneip_set.all()]
    return u', '.join(clientes)
 get_clientes.short_description = 'Clientes'
```

Comment: Does it work if the relation is being done in the inline class? The foreignKey is not in the main class.

Comment: That really has nothing to do with it. This is all based on the models not their respective admin configurations. However, it won't work in this case, because there's not just one related object, but many related objects. You would need to loop through `obj.movimentotelefoneip_set.all()` and construct some sort of string that you could return.

Comment: To make this kind of query, do I use the same way in views.py?

Comment: For the purposes of `list_display` it's all about getting whatever data you want to present in some string form that can just be printed to the screen. Whether you would need to do the same thing in your view is entirely dependent on what you're trying to do in your view. However, most likely, no, because you would normally just pass the queryset into the context and let your template determine how it renders.

Comment: What I want to do is to show all rows of the model where cliente(customer) = Google, Google is in the inline class on field Cliente. I'd like cliente in my list_display.

Comment: Like I said, you would have to loop through the related queryset and construct some string display for that. There's not just one `cliente`, there's many; one for each related `MovimentoTelefoneIP`.

Comment: I got it, but how do I use the result in the list_display?

Comment: Like I showed you above. You just reference the method name as if it was a just another field.

Comment: I edited my post, it didn't work, it gave me a header called get_related_filed the values were all "Nothing" in the admin page.

Comment: Tried it and I got the same result

Comment: Did you copy it exactly as I did or it or did you modify it again?

Comment: I lowercased `movimentotelefoneip_set` for a reason. You might want to hold off on changing code provided to you until you know exactly why you're changing something -- i.e. understand the code before assuming it's wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very good in python, I started learning these months, I'm sorry if I supposed the code wasn't able to solve my problem.
When I try to use the code I get an: sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, Cliente found.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just needed the last element so I did a return (clientes[-1]), it's being displayed in my display_list, but how do I use the inline fields in my list_filter and in my action